# Circuit Breaker for AWS Lambda

Tags: go, aws-lambda, circuit-breaker

Is it possible to wrap a HTTP request in the lambda handler with a Circuit-Breaker Library like gobreaker, I'm trying something like the below but not seeing the count go over 1. Maybe it's not possible with AWS lambda? I've tested both locally with SAM and deployed on AWS.

```
func handler(ctx context.Context, request events.ALBTargetGroupRequest) (events.ALBTargetGroupResponse, error) {

  resp, errBreaker := cb.Execute(func() (interface{}, error) {
    return sendHttpRequestThatFails(request, ctx)
    })

    if errBreaker != nil {
       log.Fatal("Error Breaker:", errBreaker)
    }

    return resp.(events.ALBTargetGroupResponse), nil
}


func main() {
    //global config added to global circuit breaker variable
    var st gobreaker.Settings
    st.Name = "HTTP POST Breaker"
    st.Timeout = 2
    st.OnStateChange = func(name string, from gobreaker.State, to gobreaker.State) {
       // do smth when circuit breaker trips.
       log.Info("tripped breaker name : "+name+" from "+from.String() + " to "+to.String())
    }
    st.ReadyToTrip = func(counts gobreaker.Counts) bool {
       log.Info("counts ,",counts )
       return counts.TotalFailures >= 2 // I never see this count go over 1
    }

   cb = gobreaker.NewCircuitBreaker(st)
   nrlambda.Start(handler, app)
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm answering my own question here because I found what was causing the counts to stay at 1 and not increment, the `log.fatal` line of code was killing the execution of the Lambda function and clearing all the go breaker counts and states. Remove this and the function finishes and is viable instance to be kept warm by AWS.

Answer (score 1):

An AWS lambda function is a stateless function, you can find more info here: https://blog.checkpoint.com/2020/03/18/aws-lambda-stateless-ephemeral/, so the information about variables, objects etc is lost after the function run and starts fresh with the next start.
To implement a CB in a stateless env you have to store the state of the function call in an external database/cache etc (for aws it may be dynamoDb table, Elasticache redis, SNS queue etc). So it's possible to do it, but it has a bit of a twist.

Comment: Thanks I'm aware of this pattern, what I'm trying to achieve is a simple in-memory breaker, I got the above to work by removing the fatal log.